# How to programmatically detect if the iCloud is enabled on user's device when only use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore?

Tags: ios, detect, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I am using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` to sync some preference data to iCloud. I found that if the user disable "Document & Data" item of iCloud in "Setting App", `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` can not synchronize its data to iCloud. So, I want to first check if this setting is switched on. I found this Code snippet：

```
    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                   URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSLog(@"url=%@",ubiq);
    if (!ubiq) {
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please enable iCloud in Setting app" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [av show];
        return;

    }
```

What I want to know is whether this is the only way to detect, even if I just use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` (not iCloud document storage). Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` is always available, even if the user does not have an iCloud account (in this case, `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` is just a simple local storage). So in general, you don't need to ask yourself or the user if there is a configured iCloud account.

If you really want to know for sure, in iOS 5, the only solution is the one you're mentioning.

Comment: Your answer seems to be in conflict with the docs, which say: “Avoid using this class for data that is essential to your app’s behavior when offline […]”. I already posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23662856/251760) about that. Would you be able to answer that?

Comment: What this means is that you should not rely on this store to be your local truth but more of a simple sync communication channel between your devices.

Comment: Thanks! I made your reply into an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26556553/251760) to my question, I hope you're fine with that. (If you'd rather make the answer yourself, I'd happily delete mine.)

Comment: @Julien Does it mean we need to maintain another local copy? Sorry, your comment and answer is still not clear.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if the docs have been updated, but Apple is now saying:

> To determine if iCloud is available, especially at launch time, check
>   the value of the ubiquityIdentityToken property instead

See [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:) for both `ubiquityIdentityToken` and `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier`.

Note also that Apple is saying that `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier` can be relatively slow, and that checking `ubiquityIdentityToken` is relatively fast.

This is for iOS6 and higher.

Comment: This true if you use iCloud Documents, the question is about the iCloud key-value storage.

Comment: Hmmm. Am I not getting something? The docs for ubiquityIdentityToken don't suggest it is specific to iCloud Documents: "When iCloud is currently available, this property [i.e., ubiquityIdentityToken] contains an opaque object representing the identity of the current user. If iCloud is unavailable for any reason or there is no logged-in user, the value of this property is nil."

Comment: As Julien said, the key-value storage is always available (even when `ubiquityIdentityToken` is nil). We want to check if the user disabled Settings > iCloud > Document & Data.